# A logarithmic integral question: $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^2{x}\ln^2{(1-x)}} {1+x}dx$

Tags: integration

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^2{x}\ln^2{(1-x)}} {1+x}dx$$
Can the integral be calculated in terms of well known constants?

Comment: @Cadenza I think it's not a duplicate since the OP asked a different question with addition *in terms of well known constants* in which isn't provided by another answer in your link.

Comment: I think this *is* a duplicate, because the answers to the other integral basically show that this integral has no hope for a simple form. `;)`